# Ionic http.post and mapping result to json

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to use http.post as described on https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/

I make an API call, I should get back some JSON and then if `data.status` is `success` then I set an element in the local storage and then change the root.

I am getting two errors when I try `ionic serve`

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'string'.

This relates to the `if(data.status == 'success') {` line

And

> Property 'token' does not exist on type 'HTTPResponse'.

And this relates to the `this.storage.set('myToken', data.token);` line

My full code is below. It seems like `data` isn't being expected to be `json` ?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';

import { FixturesPage } from '../fixtures/fixtures';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  email: string;
  password: string;  

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public http: HTTP, private storage: Storage) {
  }

  loginNow() {

    this.http.post('https://api.domain.com/login', { email: this.email, password: this.password } , { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } } ).then(data => {
        if(data.status == 'success') {
            this.storage.set('myToken', data.token);
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(FixturesPage);
        } else {
            alert("Your login details are incorrect");
        }
    }); 

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should map the response to json. To do so, import the rxjs map operator, and then add it to your post request:

```
loginNow() {
    this.http.post('https://api.domain.com/login', { email: this.email, password: this.password } , { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } } ).then(data => {
      if(data.data.status == 'success') {
        this.storage.set('myToken', data.data.token);
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(FixturesPage);
      } else {
         alert("Your login details are incorrect");
      }
    }); 

}
```

**EDIT** as the documentation says, you need to use the `data` property of the response

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This gives me Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Promise<HTTPResponse>'.

Comment: Do you have a console.log of what your data is?

Comment: I am seeing these errors when I first run ionic serve. I don't get chance to enter my login details, trigger loginNow() and see any response. This is like a syntax error before anything starts up

Comment: Comment that out, and console log the data

Comment: There's nothing to output, my loginNow() function isn't being called

Comment: What's the difference between your edited answer and my original code? I can't see any change. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It uses `data.data.status` insted of `data.status`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164294/discussion-between-chesterlaborde-and-chris).